# Setting up a Loop

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to do a program that takes the input for one of three initials A, B, C (lets just say three families initials) and then prompts for the a number(sales). the program needs to keep asking for another one for three initial and then for another number. at the ended when the user types in Z the program ends but displays the total sales amount for each family.

I'm have a lot of trouble as to how to setup such a program.

a nudge in the right direction would be great.

http://postimg.org/image/9heb6c403/

If you wanted to see the question

Yes its console base.
Feel bad for showing the code off but

```
        string QUIT = "Z";
        string quit = "z";
        string purchaseString;
        string mainString;
        double salesA = 0;
        double salesB = 0;
        double salesC = 0;
        string andr1 = "a";
        string andr2 = "A";
        string bow1 = "b";
        string bow2 = "B";
        string clax1 = "c";
        string clax2 = "C";
        double purchase;

        Console.WriteLine("To begin press anykey. To see total enter Z or Z ");
        mainString = Console.ReadLine();
        while ((mainString == andr1 || mainString == andr2) || mainString != QUIT && mainString != quit)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the persons Intials: ");
            mainString = Console.ReadLine();
            if (mainString == andr1 || mainString == andr2)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter next purchase amount: ");
                purchaseString = Console.ReadLine();
                purchase = Convert.ToDouble(purchaseString);
                salesA += purchase;
            }
            if (mainString == bow1 || mainString == bow2)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter next purchase amount: ");
                purchaseString = Console.ReadLine();
                purchase = Convert.ToDouble(purchaseString);
                salesB += purchase;
            }
            if (mainString == clax1 || mainString == clax2)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter next purchase amount: ");
                purchaseString = Console.ReadLine();
                purchase = Convert.ToDouble(purchaseString);
                salesC += purchase;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total for Anderson, Bowman and Claxton respectively is {0} {1} {2}", salesA.ToString("c"), salesB.ToString("c"), salesC.ToString("c"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

is there another way to start it without the

Console.WriteLine("To begin press anykey. To see total enter Z or Z ");
mainString = Console.ReadLine();
while ((mainString == andr1 || mainString == andr2) || mainString != QUIT && mainString != quit)

Doesn't seem necessary

Comment: Not enough info - is this a console application, a web application or window based? Are you having trouble defining the project or understanding how loops work? Have you tried hoping through examples e.g. on CodeProject.com?

Comment: You'll get even more minuses if you won't even try to show what have you tried to accomplish the task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pseudocode :

```
Set salesA, salesB, salesC = 0
While choice != 'Z'
Begin
    Initials = InputString
    Number = InputNumber
    If string[0] == 'A' Then salesA += Number
    Else If string[0] == 'B' Then salesB += Number
    Else If string[0] == 'C' Then salesC += Number
End
Print salesA, salesB and salesC
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you... In the end i figured it out awhile after reading your pseudocode. Again thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some nudges:

`Console.ReadKey()` reads a single character of input from the user.

After using `string variableName = Console.ReadLine();` to get an input from a user as a string, you can then use a `try`-`catch` pair to see if it can be converted into a number or not.

You use `while` loops to keep repeating an action.  At the end of each loop, set a conditional `bool` variable based on whether or not the user entered 'z' or whatever is the conditional for ending the program.

Let us know if you have some particular problem when debugging.